# moment js not updating in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, momentjs, mongoose-schema

So I am having trouble with momentjs. The timestamp is not updating when I make a post call. I waited for 30 seconds to make another post call and I still get the same time. How can I fix this? Below is my code so let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var moment = require('moment');
var now = moment();

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, default: ''},
    name: { type: String, default: ''},
    password: { type: String, default: ''},
    timestamp: {type: String, default: now.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('UserSchema', UserSchema);

module.exports = {
    find: function(params, callback) {
        User.find(params, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err, null);
                return;
            }
            callback(null, result);
            return;
        });
    },
    create: function(params, callback) {
        User.create(params, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err, null);
                return;
            }
            callback(null, result);
            return;
        });
    }
}

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  UserController.create(req.body, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        confirmation: 'fail',
        message: err
      });
      return;
    }
    res.json({
      confirmation: 'success',
      result: result
    });
    return;
  });
  return;
});
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please put the document text itself in the question instead of using screenshots. Also, can you include your code that's using momentjs?

Comment: and also put the code as well states what you have done so far...

Comment: updated! Thanks much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line of code will only be executed once, when the module is loaded:

```
var now = moment();
```

So the same value of `now` will be used for *all* documents.

Instead, your schema definition should use a function which will be called each time a new document is created:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, default: ''},
    name: { type: String, default: ''},
    password: { type: String, default: ''},
    timestamp: {
        type: String, 
        default: () => moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")
    }
});
```

As a side note, consider using a `Date` data type instead of `string` for your timestamp as it's more flexible and efficient.

Comment: I am still getting the same timestamp object as it was before

Comment: Hey I fixed it. Thanks!